# Metrics on the set of natural numbers

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to find a metric d on $ \mathbb{N} $ that is not equivalent to the discrete metric $ d_{\{0,1\}} $.

Thus far I got a metric with the following properties: $ d(x, x_n)  \in [0,1) \forall n \in   \mathbb{N}  $ .

However I am now adding the property: $ \lim d(x,x_n) = d_{\{0,1\}} (0,1) = 0 $

I am dissatisfied with my results thus far, cause $ \lim d_{\{0,1\}} (x,x_n) $ seems ill defined, even if adding: $ x_n \neq x \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ and I would need that for the existence of that limit for the proof.

Can someone provide a metric with the given properties in the comments?

Comment: But $d_{\{0,1\}}(0,1)=1$, isn't it? And for which sequences should the limit property hold?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a metric on $\mathbb N$ according to which there are no isolated points:
Let $$d(n,m)=\left|e^{in}-e^{im}\right|.$$

Comment: What is the $i$ at the end?

Comment: @Adayah The imaginary unit, $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Alternatively, map $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb R^2$, $n\mapsto (\cos n,\sin n)$ (this is injective because $\pi$ is irrational) and define $d(n,m)=|f(n)-f(m)|$ where the $|\cdot|$ denotes Euclidean distance in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The $p$-adic metrics are important metrics on $\mathbb N$ that have the property $$\liminf_{y\in\mathbb N}d(x,y)=0$$
for all $x$. As Hagen von Eitzen points out, another way to say this is that there are no isolated points. For example, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x,x+p^n)=0,$$
so you can take the sequence $x_n=x+p^n$.

Comment: "The p-adic metrics are important metrics" - Why are they considered important?

Comment: @Filippo The "why" is a good question, but I don't think I can do it justice. Suffice it to say that, as an empirical observation about the practice of mathematics, they are.